# Point dynamic the Firebase database

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to build a simple framework on Flutter + Firebase, but unfortunately I have a big problem.
Construction of the framework makes sense when you can dynamically point any database in the application downloaded from the store (each customer has a different database, but the application in the store is one).
Unfortunately, from what I understand, the connection data to Fierbase must be in the google-service.json file in the source code.
Is there any way to point dynamic the Firebase database?

Answer (score 1):

google-services.json is not required to initialize Firebase.  You can [take control of initialization](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/take-control-of-your-firebase-init-on.html) by calling [FirebaseApp.initializeApp()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/FirebaseApp) on your own with the values you specify.  You can also use the [Play services documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file) to help.